# Why can PowerShell not run Python with activated environment, but runs when environment is deactivated?

Tags: python, powershell, visual-studio-code

I ran in *Terminal* of *Visual Studio Code*:

```
(.env) PS C:\Users\ekuul\Desktop\GreatProjects\Room reservation system\main\backend-api> python
No Python at 'C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe'
(.env) PS C:\Users\ekuul\Desktop\GreatProjects\Room reservation system\main\backend-api> deactivate
PS C:\Users\ekuul\Desktop\GreatProjects\Room reservation system\main\backend-api> python
Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Why is this happening?

I can't run `python` with activated environment. I tried with **cmd** and **PowerShell** (in *vscode*, <kbd>Win+R</kbd>) as well but it did not work. 
 I want to work with virtual environment since all my libraries are there!

Answer (score 0):

##### The following suggestions are for your reference:

- It looks like your environment variable has `C:\Program files\Python310\python.exe` set.

  Please modify it to `C:\Program files\Python310` ( *remove `python.exe`* )
- Try to activate python interactive window with `py` in terminal

  [image]
- Use the **Python: Start REPL** command to open a python interactive window

  *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette, then search for and select **Python: Start REPL***

  [image]

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

How I solved it:
Actually, the problem was not in powershell or cmd, they were just trying to find a python executable, which did not exist.

Solution: Check your environment settings in `.env/pyvenv.cfg`. Set `home` to a correct path to your Python executable.

Here is a picture of what it should look like:

[image: picture]